# Connected Ubuntu to AD, but can't login

Tags: ubuntu, active-directory, windows-authentication

I am using a Linux box to connect to the school AD. The process has gone well, but I'm unable to login.

```
realm list

VINCI.IISCORNI.IT
  type: kerberos
  realm-name: VINCI.IISCORNI.IT
  domain-name: vinci.iiscorni.it
  configured: kerberos-member
  server-software: active-directory
  client-software: sssd
  required-package: sssd-tools
  required-package: sssd
  required-package: libnss-sss
  required-package: libpam-sss
  required-package: adcli
  required-package: samba-common-bin
  login-formats: %U@vinci.iiscorni.it
  login-policy: allow-realm-logins
administrator@LAB-INFO-11L:~$ su VINCI\\m.missiroli
su: user VINCI\m.missiroli does not exist
administrator@LAB-INFO-11L:~$ id m.missiroli@vinci.iiscorni.it
id: ‘m.missiroli’: no such user
```

The box is a fresh Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and the server is Windows 2012.

Answer (score 2):

•   Please check whether your GDM application is configured for PAM or not. If not, then run the below command to update it and configure.

```
sudo pam-auth-update
```

After running this command, hit ‘yes’ at the command prompt and select all stars and hit ‘enter’ once again. Reboot the system and then check.
•   Also try logging in with AD name, i.e., UPN or short name via SSH, you should be able to login. Also, check whether you are verified to login to the domain joined ubuntu system by running the below command: -

```
 sudo su –
```

•   By entering the grub mode by pressing Ctrl+Alt+F3 on the login screen and entering these following commands can also work for you.

```
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
  sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Hope the above methods should work for you. Also, find the below links for more information: -

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231410/cant-log-in-on-ubuntu-20-04

Comment: Very strange. On SOME machines, it won't work. On other machines it seems to work, even though all items were starred already. Also, I can only login using the long form (user@domain)... the short form (DOMAIN\\USER) looks disabled somehow.
The configuation is the same (done via script). I am baffled.

Comment: Please check whether manual login is set to true or as such in your ubuntu systems,if yes then please set it to false so that the username is saved in cache and everytime you reboot the system, you won't have to enter it again. To check the above, please refer to the output in '/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-ubuntu.conf', if output is 'greeter-show-manual-login=true' then make it as 'greeter-show-manual-login=false'.

Answer (score 0):

I normally make a group in AD (whatever.local) called Linus_machinename_Sudoers

`sudo nano /etc/security/access.conf`

Add the lines

`+ : whatever.local\Linus_machinename_Sudoers : ALL`

`- : ALL : ALL`

save and exit then for sudoer access

`sudo  visudo`

Add the following line

`%Linus_machinename_Sudoers@whatever.local ALL=(ALL) ALL`

save and exit

then putty or ssh in a whatever.local\whoever

to join the domain in the first place

`sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y`

`sudo apt -y install realmd sssd sssd-tools libnss-sss libpam-sss adcli samba-common-bin oddjob oddjob-mkhomedir packagekit openssh-server ssh`

Test the domain is contactable

`Realm discover whatever.local`

If good

`sudo realm join whatever.local`

Test you have joined

`id whatever.local\\whoever`

Comment: I keep seeing .local in instructions, what does that mean? shouldn't it just be "whatever.com" if that's the domain you are joining? confused, thank you for help!

Comment: .local is used if You created a local domain for testing or modelling, or whatever purposes, and the domain isn't actually visible to the outside world.